# How to keep event subscriptions from blocking garbage collection

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection

I have a class (Model) an object of which serves as a blueprint for (short-lived) objects of another class (ModeledRelation). Model defines an event ModeledRelation always subscribes to in order to be notified when Model changes, so ModeledRelation objects can reflect these changes 1:1.

Now ModeledRelation objects are used somewhere else for some time and then finally go out of scope. But because the event still holds a reference to them they prevent garbage collection.

Of course I formally want the objects to be GC'ed already if the event is the only reference left. I know I can unsubscribe from the event in ModeledRelation.Dispose but that would require explicitely calling Dispose and this feels a little too crafty for a purely managed class. I also want to be safe in the case that the ModeledRelation object silently slips out of scope and not have a memory leak then.

Maybe I am thinking in a totally wrong direction and this has to be done differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the Weak Event Patterns :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns

Comment: Interesting, though I don't really get what this approach wants to achieve because in the end you will have to explicitly call a method (SomeEventWeakEventManager.RemoveHandler(source, OnSomeEvent) to unsubscribe the event, which I wanted to avoid...

Comment: @oliver as I understand WeakReference (and I think this is used in WeakEventManager) It allows to collect an object even if the source of the event hold a reference by the delegate registered in its event. That means your ModeledRelation can be collected by the GC without explicitly remove the event handler. See WeakReference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx) There is a method TryGetTarget to retrieve the actual reference if it still exists.

Comment: okay, I didn't understand this. I will keep that it mind next time I arrive at a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon meditating about the problem throughout the day I have recognized what is the core issue about my approach: subscribing to the event during construction of ModeledRelation. This leads to the natural conclusion that unsubscription has to be done during object destruction... which never happens because event still points to the object and GC is blocked.

Instead the right solution to the problem is to subscribe to the event when the ModeledRelation is actually **used** (in my case added to another object's collection). Because then the natural moment to unsubscribe is when it **ceases to be used** (if it is removed from the collection of the other object). If it is reused afterwards it will resubscribe, whereas if it slips out of scope it will just be GC'ed because no events point to it anymore!